# For what values of $x$ series will converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series I am having is $\sum \left(\frac{1}{x^{n}+x^{-n}}\right)$.Rewriting it we will get $\sum \left(\frac{x^{n}}{x^{2n}+1}\right)$.At $x=1$,clearly series is going to diverge.At $x=-1$,series is Grandi's series so it is divergent.Using some comparison I am quite sure series will converge for $x>1$ and also for $x<-1$.At $0$ it seems series will converge as it is just $0$+$0$+...Now only thing I am not getting for $x$ in between $-1$ and $1$.Have I done right upto the mark.

Comment: The series is not defined at $0$!! What is the range of $n$? You need to tell us please. Why not try $x=1/2$ and see what happens?

Comment: By symmetry the convergence/divergence is the same for $x=r$ as it is for $x=1/r$. ($r\neq 0$).

Comment: @zhw..sorry for late reply..$n$ is natural no. starting from $1$ and onwards..At $x=1/2$..series is convergent so can assume it is convergent for all values in between $-1 & 1$..and I thought series is defined at $0$ by looking at the second form that I write.Why is that not valid?

Comment: @omkar The series converges on $(1,\infty)$ iff it converges on $(0,1)$ and similarly for $x<0$.